# Mathematic formula for increasing a number by a percentage every other time

Tags: finance

I'm trying to create a formula where a number is increased by a certain percentage, then next calculation it is not, then the next calculation it is, then the next calculation it is not... Basically a pattern of increasing a number every other time the calculation is run. Here is an example:

Starting amount: $\$100,000$

Bi-Annual Percentage Increase: $25\%$

Year 1 Calculation: $\$100,000 * (1+.25) = \$125,000$

Year 2 Calculation: $\$125,000$ (stays the same as previous year)

Year 3 Calculation: $\$125,000 * (1+.25) = \$156,250$

Year 4 Calculation: $\$156,250$ (stays the same as previous year)

and so on...

Isn't there a formula to perform this calculation for a set amount of years?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is, using exponentiation and the floor function.

The floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor $ gives you the largest integer $n$ such that $n\leq x$.

If $x$ is a natural number then it is either even or odd.

- If it is even it has the form $x=2n$ in which case $x/2=n$ is an integer and hence $\lfloor n\rfloor=n$.
- If it is odd then $x=2n+1$ and so $x/2=n+1/2$, and hence $\lfloor n+1/2\rfloor=n$

As we want the increase to happen when $n$ is odd we need to add the extra $+1$ to make up for this.
The resulting function is then
$$100,000\cdot (1+0.25)^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}$$ where $n$ denotes the number of years that have passed.

Answer (score 1):

The function is

$a(n)=\begin{cases}  100,000\cdot (1.25)^{n/2}, \text{ if n is even} \\ 100,000\cdot (1.25)^{(n+1)/2}, \text{ if n is odd}\end{cases} $

*Numerical example:*

For $n=5$ (odd) the amount of money is $100,000\cdot (1.25)^{(5+1)/2}=100,000\cdot (1.25)^{3}=\$195,312.5$

Comment: Note that $\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor = n/2$ if $n$ is even, $(n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd, and compare the other answer to this one.

Comment: @DavidK  I do not understand where do you want to go. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: I'm observing that the two answers give the same formula, just expressed in slightly different ways. (In effect, this answer explicitly spells out the different cases of the "floor" function that were used in the earlier answer.)

Comment: @DavidK Now I understand the purpose of your comment. It was more or less a general comment, not especially for me.